# Overload new operator for whenever new is called in my class, not for new objects of my class

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to overload the new operator in a class but it does not work. When I try to overload it globally, it does work but not in a class.

I have these 2 in my class, but when new is called in a class for an int or something,  it does not run. If I take it out of the class (global) it does work.

**EDIT: It looks like the new overload is designed to run when an object of my class type is created with new. I want to instead make it run when anything new is made inside my class. How do I do this?**

```
void* LeakCheck::operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout << "Allocating memory..." << endl;
    auto newObject = memoryManager.allocate(size); //calls malloc
    return newObject;
}

void LeakCheck::operator delete(void* objectPtr) noexcept
{
    cout << "Deallocating memory..." << endl;
    void** ptr = reinterpret_cast<void**>(objectPtr);
    memoryManager.deallocate(ptr, 0); //calls free
}
```

Comment: Take what you have here and wrap it in a minimal class, tack on a `main` that uses the minimal class, and if you still have a problem, you'll have a really good question.

Comment: "I want to instead make it run when anything new is made inside my class" - that's not how new-replacement in C++ works. Such feature does not exist in C++. When you replace `operator new` for class `LeakCheck`, it will only be used when creating `LeakCheck` objects.

Comment: So how can I do what I am trying to do? Is there another method? Is there a way to tell from what class new was called if I instead make my new overload global?

Comment: I can see approximating what you want by having the objects under test inherit from a class with overloaded `new`/`delete`, but I think you would be better off with global `new`/`delete` and conditional compilation to turn it on and off. Not sure I'd want to play that game with production code, though.

Comment: The only way is, within your class, to use a dedicated method of managing memory.   That is distinct from any overloading of operator new.   As an example, the standard containers (`std::vector`, etc) use an allocator.   The allocators which are used by default (typically) employ operator `new` in some form, and it is necessary to implement a different allocator to change how memory is allocated.   But the standard containers do not use operator `new` directly.

Comment: Ok, I was originally using global overload but I wanted to put a log of all of the allocations in a map and the map uses new for inserting and that caused a stackoverflow. That is why I even made a class for just this purpose. That is my whole goal. To keep track of new and delete.

Comment: the mapname.insert(p); uses new and that was a problem because it would call itself

Comment: Well, you could simply not use a map for logging. Or any object that relies on `operator new` for its memory allocation. Write a custom logbook that `malloc`s memory, instead of `new`ing it, and you'll avoid your infinite recursion.

Comment: I need to use an stl map though. Is there any other way?